# AWS AppSync Exceeded maximum endpoint per user count 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

During development of an AppSync app I get this message

`Exceeded maximum endpoint per user count 10`

But there are only two APIs in the AppSync console and there are no endpoints in API Gateway. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: can you provide more detail about what action was performed to trigger this message?

Comment: I created and deleted several APIs while learning how AppSync works. I don't have a lot of confidence in editing their SDL code for the schema, so I start from scratch every time I need to change something.

Comment: Are you still receiving this message? If yes, can you share your AWS account number and approximately when you received this message? I'll pull up our logs to see what's going on.

Comment: Forgive me if I don't feel comfortable sharing that information on a public website. Is there a way to do it through AWS?

Comment: You can DM me on Twitter. I'm @appwiz.

Comment: @RohanDeshpande
I see the same problem but it comes from a pintpoint PUT request 400 Bad Request
{"RequestID":"***","Message":"Exceeded maximum endpoint per user count 10"}